# Правописание "н" и "нн" в прилагательных и причастиях

Tags: орфография, прилагательные, причастия

Почему такие слова, как "медленный", "нечаянный", "читанный", "чванный" стали исключениями? Понятно, что, например, "ядреный", "мореный", "вороненый" пишутся с одной "н" потому, что связь с глаголами утеряна. А что насчет первых слов? Просто исключения и все? Никакого повода?

Comment: Вы задаете интересные вопросы, но никак не оцениваете ответы. Что-нибудь вас не устраивает? Тогда напишите, пожалуйста, об этом в комментариях.  Какие у вас будут пожелания к качеству ответов?

Comment: Например (как вариант): Мне нравятся короткие ответы по существу, длинных сочинений писать не надо. Ссылки не нужны.